# Gamedig server game status

Tags: npm, mta

i am trying to start the bot to show the status of an mta server and i am getting these errors, why?

Logged : Brasileiros Vivendo no Stylo#1128
Successfully registered application commands.
Error: Failed all 2 attempts
at QueryRunner.run (/home/runner/MTA-Discord-Status2/node_modules/gamedig/lib/QueryRunner.js:95:21)
at async Gamedig.query (/home/runner/MTA-Discord-Status2/node_modules/gamedig/lib/index.js:11:16)
Attempt #1 - Port=22126 Retry=0:
Error: UDP - Timed out after 2000ms
at Timeout. (/home/runner/MTA-Discord-Status2/node_modules/gamedig/lib/Promises.js:7:25)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
Attempt #2 - Port=22003 Retry=0:
Error: UDP - Timed out after 2000ms
at Timeout. (/home/runner/MTA-Discord-Status2/node_modules/gamedig/lib/Promises.js:7:25)

I tried with other servers, other ip's